# check whether a variable value same to mysql database table values

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

> database.connect(0,"insert into art values(database.connect(1,"select bookno from book where name='"+name+"'"),'"+Agegroup+"','"+fp+"')");

this is the code i made for insert values for two tables.database is the my class that made database connection and( conn) and statement ( stmt). I used a parameter 1 and 0 to identify for whether it is used with executequery() or execute update if 1st parameter is 1 it is executed with executeupdate() and if 0 it is executed with executequery().and art table is a child table book of table and the first column of art table exist with that foreign key referenced by book table so I wrote this code for insert first column , agegroup-seccond column and third column -fp.so this is not working how should i correct this?

Comment: I want to help but could not understand question clearly. Can you re-phrase ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two separate connections and split your one query into two, it needs to be one connection and one query. Something like

```
database.connect(0,"insert into art select bookno, Agegroup, fp from book where name='" + name + "'");
```

I am not sure what `Agegroup` and `fp` is here but my main point is the one connection, one query is a must.